# Run truffle test, returns TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null

Tags: web3js, truffle-test

after deleting several unnescesary smart contracts I was able to run `npx Truffle Test` and this is what my console returns...

```
sing gas limit: 6500 K
Using gas price: 10 Gwei
Optimizer enabled: true
Using default mnemonic: true
Using default mnemonic

Compiling your contracts...
===========================
> Compiling ./contracts/AuctioneerManaged.sol
> Compiling ./contracts/DutchXPriceOracle.sol
> Compiling ./contracts/IDutchX.sol
> Compiling ./contracts/Migrations.sol
> Compiling ./contracts/MockContracts.sol
TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null
    at detectErrors (/Users/kalebamarante/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/compile-solidity/run.js:293:61)
    at run (/Users/kalebamarante/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/compile-solidity/run.js:37:29)
    at Object.sourcesWithDependencies (/Users/kalebamarante/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/compile-solidity/index.js:78:49)
    at necessary (/Users/kalebamarante/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/compile-solidity/index.js:40:1)
    at /Users/kalebamarante/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/workflow-compile/index.js:38:1
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at compile (/Users/kalebamarante/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/workflow-compile/index.js:28:1)
    at Object.compile (/Users/kalebamarante/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/workflow-compile/index.js:67:38)
    at Object.compileAndSave (/Users/kalebamarante/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/workflow-compile/index.js:92:38)
    at Object.compileContractsWithTestFilesIfNeeded (/Users/kalebamarante/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/core/lib/test.js:247:38)
    at Object.run (/Users/kalebamarante/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/core/lib/test.js:105:27)
Truffle v5.1.45 (core: 5.1.45)
Node v16.4.0
```

My mentor is telling me that there might be something wrong with the test.js file. Is there anything specific I should look for. One more thing, I didn't write the code, I'm just trying to test the forked repo, Gnosis Oracle Price Contract.

Comment: From the stacktrace the problem seems to be during smart contracts compilation, so it looks like a problem with truffle. I'll suggest to try using an older node version, some times truffle or a dependency needs to be updated. Try the node LTS. You can report the issue at their github repo.

Comment: thank you, I honestly hate using truffle, it always gave me problems. Hardhat and Ethers are WAY BETTER for testing smart contracts!!