# Compiling contract failes

Tags: solidity, truffle, tokens, truffle-migration

I want to create crowdsale, but when compiling contracts i got:

```
Compiling your contracts...
===========================
> Compiling ./contracts/Migrations.sol
> Compiling ./contracts/TubblySale.sol
> Compiling ./contracts/TubblyToken.sol
> Compiling @openzeppelin/contracts/GSN/Context.sol
> Compiling @openzeppelin/contracts/crowdsale/Crowdsale.sol
> Compiling @openzeppelin/contracts/math/SafeMath.sol
> Compiling @openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol
> Compiling @openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20Detailed.sol
> Compiling @openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol
> Compiling @openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/SafeERC20.sol
> Compiling @openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Address.sol
> Compiling @openzeppelin/contracts/utils/ReentrancyGuard.sol
TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null
    at detectErrors (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/compile-solidity/run.js:244:61)
    at run (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/compile-solidity/run.js:39:29)
    at Object.sourcesWithDependencies (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/compile-solidity/index.js:95:58)
    at necessary (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/compile-solidity/index.js:42:1)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/workflow-compile/index.js:38:1
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at compile (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/workflow-compile/index.js:28:1)
    at Object.compile (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/workflow-compile/index.js:71:47)
    at Object.compileAndSave (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/workflow-compile/index.js:98:47)
    at Object.run (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/core/lib/commands/migrate.js:204:1)
    at Command.run (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/core/lib/command.js:140:1)
Truffle v5.3.0 (core: 5.3.0)
Node v14.14.0
```

I tried with lower truffle version as in:
[Run truffle test, returns TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/103152/run-truffle-test-returns-typeerror-cannot-read-property-0-of-null) but i didn't help, and and it's hard to find LTS versions.

package.json:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@openzeppelin/contracts": "^2.5.0",
    "@truffle/hdwallet-provider": "^1.4.3",
    "truffle": "^5.3.5"
  }
}
```

I don't think it is connected with errors inside my contracts since they are just inheriting from ERC20 and Crowdsale, but if you want to see them:

TubblyToken.sol:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity >=0.5.0 <0.9.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20Detailed.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/GSN/Context.sol";

contract TubblyToken is Context, ERC20, ERC20Detailed {
    constructor (
        string memory name,
        string memory symbol,
        uint256 initialSupply
    ) public ERC20Detailed(name, symbol, 18) {
        _mint(_msgSender(), initialSupply);
    }
}
```

TubblySale.sol:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity >=0.5.0 <0.9.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/crowdsale/Crowdsale.sol";

contract TubblySale is Crowdsale {
    constructor(
        uint256 rate,
        address payable wallet,
        IERC20 token
    ) public Crowdsale(rate, wallet, token) {}
}
```

Any help highly appreciated.